# "This may be due to a corruption of the heap" while programing in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to convert a code using assembly to sort an array of numbers; but when I try to run it I get

> "This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in IntercambioDirecto_Ens.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded."

I'm using the bubble sort algorithm (I think that's its name in English)

This is the original code (it works fine):

```
    int[] IDS(int[] A, Boolean ord){
        int aux;
        int i = 0;
        while(i<=A.Length-1 && !band){
            band = true;
            for(j = 0; j < A.Length-1; j++){
                if(ord){
                    if(A[j]>A[j+1]){
                        aux = A[j];
                        A[j] = A[j+1];
                        A[j+1] = aux;
                        band = false;
                    } 
                }else{
                    if(A[j]<A[j+1]){
                        aux = A[j];
                        A[j] = A[j+1];
                        A[j+1] = aux;
                        band = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return A;
    }
```

And I tried to create the same program in assembly (using an array of 20 numbers)

```
void ordenar()
{
  _asm
  {
    mov ecx,20
    mov auxCiclo, 20
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 0
    mov esi, arr
    ciclo1:
        cmp band,1
            je salir

        mov band,1
        mov auxCiclo, ecx
        mov ecx,20
        ciclo:
            cmp orden,0 
                je ifdesc

                mov eax, [esi+ebx]
                mov a1, eax 
                mov eax, [esi+ebx+4]
                cmp a1, eax 
                    add ebx,4
                    loop ciclo

                ifdesc:
                    mov eax, [esi+ebx]
                    mov a1, eax
                    mov eax, [esi+ebx+4]
                    cmp a1, eax
                        jl intercambio
                        add ebx,4
                    loop ciclo

                intercambio1:
                add ebx,4 
        loop ciclo
        mov ecx, auxCiclo
        mov ebx,0
        cmp j,0
            jg ciclo1
    loop ciclo1
    jmp salir 
                    intercambio:
                        mov eax, [esi+ebx]
                        mov aux, eax
                        mov eax, [esi+ebx+4]
                        mov [esi+ebx],eax
                        mov eax, aux
                        mov [esi+ebx+4], eax
                        mov band,0
                        jmp intercambio1 

    salir:
  }
}
```

But when I try to run it gives me an error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and comment your code. That said, all the `loop ciclo` instructions look suspicious - remember they will continue execution there when the loop terminates.

Comment: @Oscar - In a high level language, the compiler will help you skip the else part after executing the if. In assembly you have to do that yourself.